# how to create a radiobutton in ios

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5

I need show a `radiobutton` from the `json` given below.Can anyone suggest me how to show a `radiobutton` with multiple options.The options are also provided in `json`.

```
[{"cssClass":"radio","values":"Radio 1","fieldsize":"null","required":"undefined","prevalue":"undefined","autocaps":"none","fieldesc":" ","options":"Choice1,Choice2,Choice3,Choice,Choice"},{"cssClass":"radio","values":"Radio2","fieldsize":"null","required":"undefined","prevalue":"undefined","autocaps":"none","fieldesc":" ","options":"Choice3,Choice4,Choice5,Choice"},{"cssClass":"radio","values":"Radio3","fieldsize":"null","required":"undefined","prevalue":"undefined","autocaps":"none","fieldesc":" ","options":"Choice6,Choice7,Choice8,Choice"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can take two images (one with dot inside it and one without having dot). Give these images pragmatically to custom button on UIControlstateselected and UIControlstateNormal in some IBAction methods.

Comment: also set some integer value and check value in your action. for example when you click first time than change integer value to 1 and when you again click on same button than rechange it to 0.